# How do I fix this insertion sort visualization function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, sorting, animation

I'm making a sorting algorithm visualizer, and this is my first time attempting animation in React.
There are two major issues I keep running into. I find myself needing to close over a bunch of code in my setBarsToRender callbacks for variable scoping reasons, but that prevents me from updating other state (like highlightedIndex) at various points inside that code. Additionally, I'm struggling to write functions which have synchronous and async parts. For example, here's the code I wrote for the insertion sort animation:

```
  const insertionSort = async () => {
    for (let i = 1; i < barsToRender.length; i++) {
      if (i === barsToRender.length - 1) {
        setIsPlaying(false);
        return;
      }
      await new Promise((resolve) =>
        timers.current.push(setTimeout(resolve, 500))
      );
      let j = i;
      while (
        j > 0 &&
        barsToRender[j - 1].correctPos > barsToRender[j].correctPos
      ) {
        setBarsToRender((prev) => {
          const updatedBars = swapBarsImmutable(prev, j - 1, j);
          j = j - 1;
          return updatedBars;
        });
        await new Promise((resolve) =>
          timers.current.push(setTimeout(resolve, 500))
        );
      }
    }
  };
```

The purpose of the awaits is to stagger the animation so that each step in the procedure can be visualized. I've tried many different things like rearranging various lines of code, but the animation doesn't work as I want it to. I've managed to get selection sort and bubble sort working. Here is a basic sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-heisenberg-ydepx1?file=/src/VisualizerControls.js

I'm starting to feel that this way of animating is clunky and can get unwieldy pretty quickly. I'd appreciate help with fixing this function and any advice about animating in React in general or how you would refactor the sandbox code, since I'm pretty sure merge sort and quick sort are gonna be quite a bit harder than this.

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to separate out logic and display.  First here is a helper class to sit between logic and display:

```
function Channel () {
  const that = this;
  this.putBuffer = [];
  this.getBuffer = [];
  this.put = function (msg) {
    if (0 < that.getBuffer.length) {
      // Just put it, someone is waiting.
      let resolver = that.getBuffer.shift();
      resolver(msg);
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(true));
    }
    else {
      // Just store it and proceed.
      let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        that.putBuffer.push([msg, resolve]);
      });
      return p;
    }
  };
  this.get = function () {
    if (0 < that.putBuffer.length) {
      let b = that.putBuffer.shift();
      b[1](true); // Let putter know it is gotten.
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(b[0]));
    }
    else {
      let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => that.getBuffer.push(resolve));
      return p;
    }
  };
}
```

And now you can separate your sorting and display code by having the sorting logic send messages about what it is doing, and the display code can choose how to display it, timing, and so on.  Here is an example of a quicksort function which does this successfully.

```
async function quickSort (data, c) {
  let i = 0;
  let j = data.length - 1;
  await c.put(['data', data]);
  await _quickSort (data, i, j, c);
  await c.put(['done', data]);
}

async function _quickSort (data, i, j, c) {
  if (j <= i) {
    return;
  }
  await c.put(['highlight', i, j]);
  await c.put(['highlight-pivot', i]);
  let i_tmp = i;
  let j_tmp = j;
  while (i_tmp < j_tmp) {
    if (data[i_tmp+1] < data[i_tmp]) {
      await c.put(['swap', i_tmp, i_tmp+1]);
      let tmp = data[i_tmp+1];
      data[i_tmp+1] = data[i_tmp];
      data[i_tmp] = tmp;
      i_tmp++;
    }
    else {
      await c.put(['swap', i_tmp+1, j_tmp]);
      let tmp = data[i_tmp+1];
      data[i_tmp+1] = data[j_tmp];
      data[j_tmp] = tmp;
      j_tmp--;
    }
  }
  await c.put(['unhighlight-pivot', i_tmp]);
  await c.put(['unhighlight', i, j]);

  await _quickSort(data, i, i_tmp-1, c);
  await _quickSort(data, i_tmp+1, j, c);
}
```

And now you see that it gives you all of the information needed to display its internal logic without a lot of display logic embedded in it.  What information it gives can be seen easily with this:

```
async function fakeDisplay (c) {
  let msg = await c.get();
  while (msg[0] != 'done') {
    console.log(msg);
    msg = await c.get();
  }
  console.log(msg);
}

let c = new Channel();
quickSort([5, 3, 8, 1, 2, 9, 6, 4, 7], c);
fakeDisplay(c);
```

And now you can design your UI, worry about animation, and so on.  You can even keep a log of the messages, allow people to step backwards, and so on if you want!

Incidentally merge sort does have a complication.  Namely that to merge we have to copy half of it out.  Here is an implementation of that.

```
async function mergeSort (data, c) {
  let i = 0;
  let j = data.length - 1;
  await c.put(['data', data]);
  await _mergeSort(data, i, j, c);
  await c.put(['done', data]);
}

async function _mergeSort (data, i, j, c) {
  if (j <= i) {
    return;
  }
  else {
    await c.put(["highlight", i, j]);
    await c.put(["unhighlight", i, j]);
    let mid = Math.floor((i + j) / 2);
    await _mergeSort(data, i, mid, c);
    await _mergeSort(data, mid+1, j, c);
    await c.put(["to_workspace", i, mid]);
    let working = data.slice(i, mid + 1);
    let i1 = i;
    let j1 = mid + 1;
    let k1 = 0;
    console.log([data, working]);
    while ((j1 <= j) && k1 < working.length) {
      if (data[j1] < working[k1]) {
        c.put(["copy-from-data", j1, i1]);
        data[i1] = data[j1];
        i1++;
        j1++;
      }
      else {
        c.put(["copy-from-workspace", k1, i1]);
        data[i1] = working[k1];
        i1++;
        k1++;
      }
    }

    while (j1 <= j) {
      c.put(["copy-from-data", j1, i1]);
      data[i1] = data[j1];
      i1++;
      j1++;
    }

    while (k1 < working.length) {
      c.put(["copy-from-workspace", k1, i1]);
      data[i1] = working[k1];
      i1++;
      k1++;
    }
  }
}
```